# Rails ajax undefined local variable or method

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, null

I'm trying to add ajax to my app so a user can follow another user without reloading the page, but I'm getting the following error:

**Edit - correct issue**

```
undefined local variable or method `member' for #<#<Class:0x79c3cb0>:0x78b26e0>

Extracted source (around line #1):

$("#gl_follow_<%= member.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/follow_member2', :locals => {:member => @followable}) %>");
```

Here's all my relevant code:

**controllers/follows_controller.rb**

```
class FollowsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_member!

    def create
        current_member.follow(followable)
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # index.html.erb
            format.js
        end
    end

    def destroy
        current_member.stop_following(followable)
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # index.html.erb
            format.js
        end
    end
end
```

**controllers/follows_members_controller.rb**

```
class FollowsMembersController < FollowsController
    def followable
        @followable ||= Member.find_by_user_name(params[:member_id])
    end
end
```

**views/search/search.html.erb**

```
<div id="member_list_wrap">
    <%= render partial: 'members', :collection => @members, :as => :member %>
</div>
```

**views/search/_members.html.erb**

```
<div id="member_item_wrap">
    <div class="avatar">
        <%= follow_profile_link member, title: member.full_name, alt: member.full_name %>
    </div>

    <% if current_member != member && member_signed_in? %>
        <span id="gl_follow_<%= member.id %>" class="gl_follow">
            <%= render :partial => "shared/follow_member2", :locals => {:member => member} %>
        </span>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**views/shared/_follow_member2.html.erb**

```
<% if current_member.following?(member) %>
    <%= link_to (image_tag("Following.png", class: "gl_fol") + " Following"), member_follow_path(member.to_param, current_member.get_follow(member).id), :method => :delete, :remote => true, title: "Unfollow", alt: "Unfollow", :class => "btn btn-follow" %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to (image_tag("Follow.png", class: "gl_fol") + " Follow"), member_follows_path(member.to_param), :method => :post, :remote => true, title: "Follow", alt: "Follow", :class => "btn btn_gl_fol" %>
<% end %>
```

**views/follows_members/create.js.erb**

```
$("#gl_follow_<%= member.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/follow_member2', :locals => {:member => @followable}) %>");
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing. I've been able to get ajax working on a single users' page but can't get this working when there are multiple instances on users listed on the page.

I'm using `member.id` to specify which button the ajax needs to work on.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you've shown, and guessing a few pieces, I think you should have:

```
$("#gl_follow_<%= @followable.id %>").html...etc.
```

Comment: Ah yes that was it. Knew it was something I was forgetting. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it was a simple fix. Don't take it personally, but I've submitted your question for closing because it was just a simple typo and this question/answer probably won't help anyone else who comes across it.

Answer (score 0):

The views/follows_members/create.js.erb template references `@member.id`, but I do not see it being set any where in your code and everything else references `current_member`.  If `current_member` is accessible from the view change `@member.id` to `current_member`?

Comment: It was calling to this `<span id="gl_follow_<%= member.id %>" class="gl_follow">`. I removed the @ and I get this error `undefined local variable or method 'member'`. Why is it saying it's undefined?

Comment: Based on all your other code it looks like you should be using `current_member`

Comment: I'm using member so I can specify which button the ajax should be working on as there are multiple users being listed with a follow button.